ASP. NET load time fuzzing
I have a razor pages app that has user login info. After learning of the recent side channel attack in M1 hardware, I would like to avoid timing attacks in my own app. For example, a user can request a new verification email in the case of losing their own or failure to send.
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    User user = await _manager.FindUserByEmailAsync(InputModel.Email);
    if (user is null || user.EmailConfirmed)
    {
        \\ adds model error telling the user that the verification email was sent
        return Page();
    }

    string confirmationUrl = await GenerateVerificationUrlAsync(user);
    
    await _emailSender.SendAsync(user.Email, "Verify Email", await _emailRenderer.RenderConformationEmail(confirmationUrl));
    \\ adds model error telling the user that the verification email was sent
    return Page();
}

An attacker can leverage the fact that it takes longer to generate a verification email if the user doesn't have a confirmed email and would be able to camp the form and wait for user(s) to register or change their email to the target email(s). Is there a simple way, like using middleware, to fuzz the time it takes to generate a response to avoid timing attacks?

have a middleware await Task.Delay(random)?

@BenderBoy I thought of that but if it takes 20ms for negative result and 50ms for positive result, and I delay between 50 and 200ms, then it'll just move the goalpost to 70-220ms for neg and 100-250ms for a positive result. It'll just slow the attacker instead of making it statistically ambiguous.

I think the key is to make everything wait for the same amount of time.  (that would necessarily be at least the largest amount of time a task could take... which is hard to predict)  In this case, a long delay wouldn't be that big a deal, so you could just take the current time and keep checking for a certain elapsed time before returning the page.  In general though, you might benefit from a reverse proxy that performs rate limiting to slow down this kind of attack.
